# GA4- This property is denied access to the API. Contact Google Analytics API Support for more information

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am using run report api with GA data API v1beta and it is throwing me below error:

```
    "response": {
    "error": {
        "code": 429,
        "message": "This property is denied access to the API. Contact Google Analytics API Support for more information.",
        "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
    }
}
```

API doc doesn't say anything about it: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport

I am not sure what is going wrong here. Do share insights if you have any.